# Disabed element shown as enabled in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to check if element is enabled/disabled. Every time it returns that the button is enabled. I am not sure why, I hope somebody can help here.

Code:

```
bool checkIfEnabled = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#create-t-step-7 .tooltip-wrapper a")).Enabled;
```

Button is disabled. You can check the images of html here:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Enabled Property](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Enabled.htm)

> return true for everything except explicitly disabled input elements.

The element you are testing is `<a>`, not `<input>`, so the result is `true`.

You can use `GetAttribute("disabled")` instead, it will return `true` if the element has `disabled` attribute

```
bool checkIfDisabled = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#create-t-step-7 .tooltip-wrapper a")).GetAttribute("disabled");
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually used GetAttribute("disabled") and thought it is just a workaround. Now it is clear, "Enabled" property should be only used for input elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the class name which is not unique ".tooltip-wrapper" is also applied to next div also so i think it getting the enabled = true for the lower div

Try using this

#create-t-step-7 form .form-group > div.tooltip-wrapper >  a

Comment: Even if the selector matches the next `<div>`, if it have `<a>` descendant, `FindElement` will return the first result.